# What is the purpose of standardization in machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, discrete-mathematics, nearest-neighbor

I'm just getting started with learning about K-nearest neighbor and am having a hard time understanding why standardization is required. Reading through, I came across a section saying

> When independent variables in training data are measured in different
>   units, it is important to standardize variables before calculating
>   distance. For example, if one variable is based on height in cms, and
>   the other is based on weight in kgs then height will influence more on
>   the distance calculation.

Since K nearest neighbor is just a comparison of distances apart, why does it matter if one of the variables has values of a larger range since it is what it is.

Also,what exactly does standardization do to the values? One of the formulas does it by `Xs = (X-mean)/(max-min)` 
Where does such a formula come from and what is it really doing? Hopefully someone can offer me a simplified explanation or give me a link to a site or book that explains this in simple terms for beginners.

I'm not sure why this question has been put on hold as I'm looking to implement the algorithm using python but just need to understand how it works first. If this is not a suitable site to ask then please advise where I can ask as now I've been stuck for a day yet i'm sure someone here has an answer. Thanks

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/when-to-standardize-your-data-in-4-minutes-f9282190707e I liked this article on the subject.

Comment: @arowell I'll check it out thanks

Comment: note this can also be called normalisation, see https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/37223/59452 for another explanation

Comment: as to why this has been put on hold: it doesn't contain much code, which is pretty much a requirement for this site.  try https://stats.stackexchange.com/ if you want to understand the maths/theory behind it, otherwise datascience.SE might help

Comment: @SamMason Thanks for that, will post my question over there:)

Answer (score 2):

> why does it matter if one of the variables has values of a larger range

For clustering algorithms, if you don't standardize the data, the value with a larger range will have more effect on the distances used when determining which cluster a point belongs to.

Here's a visual example:

We have some input data.

```
x = [0.95, 1, 1.05, 3.95, 4, 4.05]
y = [150, 100, 50, 450, 400, 350]
```

[image]

Just looking at this, it's apparent that the distance from a point to its neighbors mostly consists of its distance on the y axis, so something like K-NN would basically give that feature all of the weight in deciding which cluster a point belonged to.

When we put the data set through your formula `Xs = (X-mean)/(max-min)`

The data set becomes

```
x = [-0.5000000000000002, -0.4838709677419357, -0.4677419354838712, 0.46774193548387094, 0.48387096774193544, 0.49999999999999983]
y = [-0.25, -0.375, -0.5, 0.5, 0.375, 0.25]
```

[image]

And now you can see the clusters are separated by both x and y values.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Im still unclear why this is necessary though, not saying that it isn’t . If KNN is all about relative distances, then its expected that the variable with the larger ranges will influence more, but the distances will be exactly what they have to be so why cant they just be used that way. Also, plotting the first graph that you used, but with x axis values ranging from 0 to 4.5 also shows the points just as separate as your second graph

Comment: you didn't say, but your KNN is probably using l2-norm, that will see the "distances" like the first plot (i.e. the x-axis basically doesn't help with discrimination).  it's the normalisation that's letting the model see the data like a plot with a rescaled x-axis

Comment: > so why cant they just be used that way


They can. There may be situations where you want one input variable to have more weight than another.

@SamMason's comment about the first plot is correct.

You can also think of normalization as "resizing the axis for the algorithm" the way you could resize the x axis of the first plot so that you could see the points separated.